# Can I view .bit domains without having internet through my ISP provider?

Tags: namecoin, websites

I think the title says it all. But I will say this, I know I can view websites hosted on my server without having internet. I just have to be viewing the site on my network.

I wanted to know that since namecoin and .bit domain names are decentralized if their is a way of connecting and viewing .bit domain names without dealing with an ISP provider?

If so can someone refer me to some good tutorials and or how to's do something like this?

Comment: You mention "websites hosted on my server" - are these your *own* websites, that you're working on developing for example?

Comment: It's a lamp server running Fedora 20 actually LAMPPP since it has Python and Perl as well I also have SSH

Comment: @GregHewgill I could open up my ports on my router but I don't want to do that

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. It would be logically impossible to view somebody else's site without having a connection to the internet, so I have to conclude that you're trying to work on your own web sites on your own computer. Is that right?

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I did answer your question. The sites are not public and can only be accessed on my LAN. They are not meant to be public, and are primarily for people to check local news about what is happening in our building. For example anyone see a hat in the building please bring it to apt: 3, please leave notify police if person shows up at the building and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, the contents of websites themselves are not distributed by namecoin. There is something that is, though: For regular internet sites, your computer would first contact a domain name server with a query of what internet protocol (IP) address this site currently has. When using namecoin's .bit domain, all the information that usually originates at domain name servers on the internet instead comes from data distributed by the namecoin network across its clients.

So, yes, there is some data that is distributed and does exist locally if you run a namecoin client. But it will only give you some minimal metadata about the sites, not any of their content.